# Display only parts of a JSON-Model in a sap.m.Tree

Tags: treeview, sapui5

I have a UI5-JSON-Model and want to display it in a tree. But I want to display not the whole structure, but only a subset. Say I have the following model:

```json
{
  "nodes": [
    {
      "text": "Leaf 1",
      "additionalStuff": [
        {
          "element": "blue"
        },
        {
          "element": "green"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "text": "Subtree",
      "nodes": [
        {
          "text": "Leaf in Subtree"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "text": "Leaf 2"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to display the `nodes` and the `text`, but not the `additionalStuff`. But the picture I get is the following:

[image: Screenshot of my sample tree]

How can I tell the tree to ignore the `additionalStuff`?

[**Live Example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/0kkQ8vKR9l9HV2q5JfPw?p=preview)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are looking for is the parameter `arrayNames` from [sap.ui.model.json.JSONTreeBinding](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.json.JSONTreeBinding).

Bind your items like this:

```
items="{path: '/nodes', parameters: {arrayNames: ['nodes', 'text']}}"
```

For complex expression bindings, you have to configure it in your bootstrapping.

```
data-sap-ui-compatVersion="edge"
```

> Complex syntax is automatically activated when the compatVersion is set to edge or to version 1.28 or higher.

Here is the documentation for [Configuration Options and URL Parameters](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/91f2d03b6f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070.html).